# Is it possible to have an Activity over a NativeActivity and still getting inputs in the NativeActivity?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a `NativeActivity` which works by itself and I try to add some SDKs ( more precisely Admob/Chartboost/Facebook ).

On the other hand I've got custom scripts which manage all the SDK only if we pass an `Activity` in the parameters.

My goal is to manage all of the SDKs with a custom `Activity` over my `NativeActivity`.

My questions :

- Is It even possible ?
- Is there a simpler solution than mine ?

So far my inputs are stucked in the `Activity`.

Here's my NDK class ( from the android-ndk examples ) :

```
public class TeapotNativeActivity extends NativeActivity {
// Some previous code
    public void showUI()
    {
        // Some previous code
        ASE_GUIActivity.pNatAct = this;
        Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(this, ASE_GUIActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(startNewActivityOpen);
    }
}
```

Here's my activity class :

```
public class ASE_GUIActivity extends Activity {

    public static NativeActivity pNatAct;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        pNatAct.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

And finally my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.teapot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hasCode="true"
        android:name="com.sample.teapot.TeapotApplication"
        >

        <!-- Our activity is the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.sample.teapot.TeapotNativeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of or .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                    android:value="TeapotNativeActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.littleworlds.ase.ASE_GUIActivity"  
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not instantiate an activity inside an activity. You can only use intent mechanism, in which case you will only have one activity running at the same time. Your design choice does not seem suitable for Android environment.

Why don't you try to launch the SDK activities you mention from native side? For example, if you want to launch a Facebook login screen when user clicks a button, get the necessary input inside native activity and then using JNI calls and intent mechanism, launch the Facebook activity.